# What is the idea behind skipping chars in the old impl of String hashCode() in Java

Tags: java, string, hash, hashcode

What is the idea of skipping some characters from a String in old versions of Java's String hashCode() implementation:

```
public int hashCode() {
   int hash = 0;
   int skip = Math.max(1, length()/8);
   for (int i = 0; i < length(); i += skip)
      hash = (hash * 37) + charAt(i);
   return hash;
}
```

In the current version there is no skipping and the prime number is 31 instead of 37

Comment: Which version is this? The algorithm has been documented since 1.1.

Comment: That code won't even compile, since `hash` is undefined, and it can't be a field, since that would cause multi-threading errors.

Comment: Quoting Algorithms Fourth Edition by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne : "Consider the following hashCode() implementation for String, which was used in early versions of Java"

Comment: Absolutely correct, Andreas, I missed the variable declaration and I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably to fast up the `hashCode()` computation but as consequence it had more potential collisions.
The new version favors less collisions but requires more computations.

But in the facts, `String`s are immutable, so in more recent versions of `hashCode()`, that is computed once :

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash; 
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        hash = h = isLatin1() ? StringLatin1.hashCode(value)
                              : StringUTF16.hashCode(value);
    }
    return h;
}
```

So in a some way it makes sense to favor this way as it reduces the collision number and not skipping some characters in the  `hashCode()` computation is not so expensive as the result is cached.